# p-adic height on CM abelian varieties

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let A be a CM abelian variety over a number field and p a prime of ordinary reduction. Is the p-adic height of a non-torsion point on A over a p-adic field non-zero? 
When A is an elliptic curve, this is a result of Bertrand.